# Parallax slider works under the link "http://localhost:33880/home" but does not work under the link "http://localhost:33880/home/Index"

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, layout, parallax

In my mvc4 application, I use the Parallax Slider in the header. I use a layout to use other sub pages. Everything is ok when I call `http://localhost:33880/home`, but when I call the   `http://localhost:33880/home/Index` or other pages that inherits from the layout, does not work.
What can cause this?
Thanks.

Comment: What you mean by `does not work`? Any errors?

Comment: No error.The parallax slider doesnt work.I checked the page sources http://localhost:33880/home and http://localhost:33880/home/galery they are same.But the slider works in first one does not work in second one.

Comment: Any js/css error in Internet Browser console window? Sometimes when we use relative referencing in links/css/images/js using `..` or `.`, moving from one url to another breaks...

Comment: what a silly mistake.Thanks for your help Pranav.The layout and other sub pages was in different location.I move my layout page same location with sub pages and its working now.Thank you very much Pranav

Answer (score 0):

You should use two dots .. before /path just like in code

```
<div class="parallax-window" 
     data-parallax="scroll" 
     data-image-src="../path/image.jpg">
</div>
```